# how to get the object array key value in other array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
dynamicFields = {
  column1: {label: "cols1" type: "FLOAT"}
  column2: {label: "cols1" type: "FLOAT"}
}
```

trying to find the value, but some reason it's not working

```js
_.find(dynamicFields, {key: column1})==undefined? true : false
```

Comment: both `column1` & `column2`  are wrong

Comment: You are missing `, in your `column1` and `column2` properties

Comment: Incorrect format of JSON

Comment: Shouldn't this: `{key: column1}` be this: `{key: 'column1'}`?

Comment: These are neither arrays nor JSON objects , but javascript object literals (which look like JSON objects but have looser formatting rules). ellipsis' solution should work nicely. Note: you are getting downvotes probably because Stack Overflow expects more research before asking a question (see http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Object.values()` to get all the values in an array, `map` it and Use `Object.entries` on individual objects to get the key and values in an array. Your JSON object is also in the wrong format

```js
var dynamicFields = {
  column1: {
    label: "cols1",
    type: "FLOAT"
  },
  column2: {
    label: "cols1",
    type: "FLOAT"
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(dynamicFields).map(e => Object.entries(e)))
```